# Help with chemistry equation

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I'm trying to reproduce the following equation using the chemfig package :

[image: goal equation]

I've been at this for a few hours, trying out different approaches but as soon as one thing works, something else seems to go wrong.

The main issue is either the brackets or the charges (or having something come after the brackets).

It doesn't need to be identical to the example. It just has to work and convey the same information.

Here are my best two attempts (there are probably errors, but it seems to partially work on Overleaf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}      


\begin{document}

2 \chemfig{R-C(-[:0]\chemabove{O}{-})=[:90]O}\chemabove{Na}{+}}
+
\chemfig{Ca^{2+}}(aq)
\ce{->}
\chemfig{{(}R-C(-[:0]O)=[:90]O}{)_2}Ca}(s)
+

\vspace{2cm}

\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{2 R-C(-[:0]\chemabove{O}{-})=[:90]O}\chemabove{Na}{+}}{}(aq)
\+
\chemfig{Ca^{2+}}(aq)
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
\chemname{\chemfig{{(}R-C(-[:0]O)=[:90]O}{)}Ca}
    {}(aq)
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image: output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Is there a special reason for not simply using something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\begin{document}
\ce{2 RCOO^-Na^+_{(aq)} + Ca^{2+}_{(aq)} -> (RCOO)_2Ca{(s)} + 2 Na^+}
\end{document}`?

Comment: I guess I wanted to highlight the double bond... I could always write it out RC(=O)O. It's a document for a class that's not very advanced, so I guess I didn't want to give them too much to figure out on their own. It's a good idea, though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code is a simplified and tweaked MWE that you've posted. In order to mimic sans font (likely Arial, as guidelines of ACS and most other publishers suggest) easier, I switched to XeLaTeX and enabled Fira (free alternative) typeface. Also, I use `chemmacros` package with all modules enabled as it offers many useful shortcuts, also for the states of aggregation (which, according to IUPAC, shouldn't be subscripts).

[image: Screenshot]

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\usepackage[math-style = ISO]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Fira Math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{
        modules = all,
    }
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{
        atom sep = 1.75em,
        bond join = true,
        bond style = {
            line width = 0.6pt
        },
    }

\begin{document}

\schemestart
2\,\chemfig{R-C(=[:90]O)-O\rlap{${}^-$}}\; \ch{Na+ \aq}
\+
\ch{Ca^2+ \aq}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
\chemleft{[}
    \chemfig{R-C(=[:90]O)-O}
\chemright{]_2}
\ch{Ca \sld}
\+
2\,\ch{Na+ \aq}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, "`chemformula` instead of `chemfig`" should most likely be "`chemformula` instead of  `mhchem`"

Comment: @leandriis I have no idea what I was thinking about at that moment when I mixed those two packages (just edited). Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks so much! It game me errors relating to fonts, but after commenting out 
```
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\usepackage[math-style = ISO]{unicode-math}
   \setmathfont{Fira Math}
```
it worked!

Comment: Re: »I use `chemformula` […] as it has […] shortcuts/macros, e.g. for the states of aggregation« – that is not true. `\aq` is defined in `chemmacros` and `chemmacros` can well be used with `mhchem` instead of `chemformula` ;)

Comment: @clemens Thank you for pointing this out. This is not the first the time you corrected me on which package does what, but I keep on mixing `chemmacros` and `chemformula` for some reason:(

Comment: @andselisk quite understandable :) `chemformula` used to be part of `chemmacros` before it got a package of itself. And per default `chemmacros` loads it instead of `mhchem`.